# Activator and implemetation bundle in same project

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, osgi-bundle

we are looking for way to add interface implementation and its bundle activator in same project to simplify process of bundle creation and activation for third party's.

i have tried modifying interface implemented bundle code by include activator class in same project but application is not recognizing this bundle

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: LocationSearch
Bundle-SymbolicName: LocationSearch
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: locationsearch.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

is it possible to implement same ?

Comment: Since you are requiring `org.eclipse.ui` and `org.eclipse.core.runtime` this is an Eclipse plug-in, **not** a plain OSGi bundle. Is that what you want? It is normal to put the activator in the bundle. I don't understand what you are saying doesn't work.

Comment: this is going to be eclipse plugin.confusion for me is how to add implemented interface and activator class in same project.all the examples require us to create separate project. ex http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077837/java-se/java-se-hello-osgi-part-1-bundles-for-beginners.html?page=4

Comment: Sorry but I still don't follow. Any Eclipse plugin can have an Activator just by having a class listed in the `Bundle-Activator` that implements `BundleActivator`. Implementing other classes is not relevant to this.

Comment: Please explain what this means: "application is not recognizing this bundle". Which application? What should it do when it "recognizes" the bundle? Are you expecting some output? Is there an error message? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cached bundle in my app prevented me to see updated code.
this feature is easily implementable